# Some pages aren't indexed with Sphider unless added manually

Tags: php, html, sphider

I recently installed Sphider onto my site and it was simple to do so and indexing the pages was very simple, however I ran into a small issue.

I have a lot (seriously loads) of pages on my site and a lot of them weren't indexed.  I have a page which takes a .csv file and creates a table using a foreach loop in PHP and the first column is a hyperlink to each item with a dedicated page for that item.  My issue arises whereby Sphider does not index these individual pages, it only indexes the table page.  I'm in a right two and eight because I have no idea why these pages are not indexed.

I checked to see if I had any  but I didn't and I even set Sphider to index a random one of the individual pages from the table and it appeared in the search.  I'd do this with all the pages but I keep adding new pages every time we get a new item so I would get inundated with things to add to the index list.

My question comes here: is there some solution where I can have a script that adds each URL to Sphider's database seeing as that seems to make them appear; or am I being a complete div and am missing something really obvious here that because of the .csv PHP table something goes wrong, maybe?

I would really appreciate your help because I am completely confused.

Thanks, Carty

PS, What's the standard for including tl; dr?  Is that just for Redditors? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem when I first started using Sphider Search that when I would try to spider a folder on my website eg.   www.mysite.com/myfolder   which contained 900 different html pages, it would only spider / list in database 1 link which was www.mysite.com/myfolder.

I Figured out That sphider wont spider a whole directory if it has a 'index.html' or 'home.html' or 'index.php' file in said folder.

So I temporarily deleted my index.html file, successfully spider'd all 900 html files.
then re-uploaded my index.html

If index & home html files are not the cause, It might be your Spidering Link Depth Settings are not high enought.

lastly Sphider search respects the rel="nofollow" attribute in  tags, so it wont index said links either.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up.  This information is well needed and I hope it will help others too.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if your page contain less then 3 words then sphider is not able to index by default. You have to change in

/sphider/settings/conf.php

as per your requirment.

```
$min_words_per_page=0;
```